# Display a grid from a clicked link using typescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I'm trying to write code that will display a grid when a link is clicked, and I managed to get the link display, but failing to get grid displayed at the  bottom of the page. Thanks for your help.

*

```
export function setCustomLinkContent(divId: string, field: propertybox.Field) {

            var container = $('#' + divId);
            container.height(70);
            container.width(260);

            container.append("<p><a target='_blank' href=\"http://localhost\">View all works</a></p>");
            this.container.prepareGridContainer();
            var gridContainer = $("#" + this.container);
            var gridContHeight = gridContainer.height() - 27 - 43;
            var workHtml =
                "<div id='" + this.workContainer + "-heading' class='orm-table-title'>" +
                "<label>" + this.headerLabel + "</label>" +
                "</div>" +
                "<div id='" + this.workContainer + "-table' class='map-work-grid' style='height: " + gridContHeight + "px'>" +
                "<table style='margin: 0 auto; width: 100%; overflow-x: auto'>" +
                "<thead>" +
                "<tr id='" + this.tableHeader + "'></tr>" +
                "</thead>" +
                "<tbody id='" + this.tableBody + "'></tbody>" +
                "</table>" +
                "</div>";
            gridContainer.append(workHtml);

        }
```

*

Comment: I suppose $("#" + this.container) does not return a JQuery object.

Comment: does that mean it has to be this.divId?

Comment: Might be. Perhaps using breakpoints in the browser and examining the variables in the current scope might help. This way you see if your current "this"-reference has a member divId, and its value.

Comment: I removed this, still no display. and it was saying reference is null

Comment: where is your prepareGridContainer() function? Is it a plugin-function declared on JQuery? Then this.container.prepareGridContainer should probably be container.prepareGridContainer(). "this" references the caller object, and may vary (for example when triggered through an event).

Comment: yes it is a function defined in a jquery plugin

Answer (score 0):

Very likely you have the wrong *this*. Since your function is not a part of a class *this* doesn't seem to make sense here.

More about `this`: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvocUcbCupA&hd=1

Comment: thanks now i understand, i will rework my code and see where i was going wrong, i will post it my code when is working. thanks